# How to use resize event to resize a form?

Tags: c++-cli

```
ref class FormEventListener
{
public:
    FormEventListener (MyForm ^form)
    {
        this->form = form;
    }
    void FormResized (Object ^sender, System::EventArgs ^args)
    {
        form->editor->Size = form->Size;
    }
private:
    MyForm ^form;
};

// MyForm class

this->Resize += gcnew System::EventHandler (formEventListener,
        &FormEventListener::FormResized);
```

I'm trying to get my textbox to expand when the window is resize?
The above is what I have so far. It's not working, however. Any clues?

Comment: There is no hint in the snippet.  Just don't do it this way, this is already provided.  Just set the "editor" control's Anchor property to all 4 sides.

Comment: Okay. I another question. Is this good practice? I mean is this a good way to handle events? Is there a better way? This is the ways I'm currently handling my events? I have another class called MenuEventListener that handles menu events.

Comment: No, not exactly.  You had to make FormResized public, event handlers ought to be private.  You could have subscribed the event in the FormEventListener constructor as well, now it *can* be private.  Yet another problem is that you had to make "editor" public as well.  These are all implementation details for the specific form class, they therefore belong in that class.  C++/CLI is not the greatest language to implement UIs, the single pass compilation model that it inherited from C++ makes programmers write bad code.

Comment: How would you suggest I change the structure?